# Remove the instance of a string in a result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
select LOCATIONS.LOCATION, LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION,
       regexp_substr(LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION, '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS col_one
from locations
where LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION like 'SUB,%'
   OR LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION like 'STATION,%'
```

and the result as follows

```
        COL_ONE   
   --------------------
     MONARCH SUBSTATION
     PRICE SUBSTATION
     DALLAS SUBSTATION
     COLFAX STATION
     BELMONT SUBSTATION
     GREAT LAKES STEEL SUBST A
     QUINCY SUBSTATION
     FRENCH LANDING SUBSTATION
     BERRY SUBSTATION DECOMMIS
     MCLOUTH SUBSTATION A
     MAZDA SUBSTATION
     BARNES LAKE SUBSTATION
```

How can I remove the word Substation, SUBST and anything that follows these words in the column COL_ONE?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `regexp_replace`.  If you're trying to get rid of text that can match a `regex` pattern, this is exactly what you need:

**Example**

`regexp_replace(LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION, 'SUBST.*$', '')`

**Pattern**

**.*** - Matches any character with a length of zero or more

**$** - Specifies the end of the string

[Source](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)